# Linker error, but only on test files

Tags: ios, core-graphics, linker-errors, libraries, target

Here's a screen capture of my app. I'm using UIKit to create a PDF from some of the app data. I get no errors on the app itself but in the test section I get a bunch of them that look like  the app can't find some CoreGraphics references. But CG is being imported in Tests.h... I can run the app, on simulator and device with no problems. Any idea what is causing this?

To add a little more to this: I imported the class where I am making the PDF into another application and I am not getting the errors there, so that's good. So any ideas what could be happening? (And yes, the libraries are in my app)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being imported but not linked. You need to link the CoreGraphics framework:

Importing a class header A into class B allows class B to know what public API (variables, properties and methods) in class A can be used by other classes and that is why you do not get any errors until you compile.

When you compile, you need the actual code (.m file if you will) to be able to execute the calls that class B is doing to class A variables, properties and methods. That code resides in the libraries/ frameworks you link to your project. Your code with the linked libraries together become the final compiled code.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Single click on your project (top left of the navigator)
2. Select your Target project
3. Click on the "Build Phases" tab
4. Click on "Link Binary with Libraries"
5. Add CoreGraphics.framework

That should solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the libraries are link. Reread my question (or check out the supplied image) - the errors are only occurring on the test files.

Comment: Dang it, you were right, I was looking at the linkage for the app, not the testing libraries...doh

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I removed the libraries, reinstalled them and did a clean and that seemed to fix the issue.